# What is the best way to make localization in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, localization

I am working on the localization in the iPhone . I have used apple in built localization technique i.e. after saying make localize in  Xcode provides two different .string file where we have to put the key and value for the localized word . I have implemented this method in my project . One more thing i have read somewhere that we can make localization by using database .I don't know how ? probably by storing the localized words in key value pair inside the database . But which is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different techniques or ways to localize iphone app, we can localize complete .xib files or prepared localized string files.

Following links will elaborate this :

```
https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common way you will find is using the `NSLocalizedString`s with a `.string` file per language. This concept should seem familiar to localizers who have used `gettext` before.

I'm not sure about putting the data into a database unless you had a *bunch* of strings that needed localizing. Otherwise, you probably won't gain much for the effort of storing the strings in a database.